# rack-rewrite redirect, duplicate content problems - SEO Rails Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, seo, middleware, http-status-code-302

I am trying to make my site SEO friendly, so I'm implementing rack-rewrite to get rid of 302 temporary redirects and duplicate content problems.

Running my site through ragepank.com gives me this:

2 pages returned a 200 response. This indicates potential for duplicate content problems. Ideally, only http://www.example.com OR http://example.com should return a 200 response.

```
http://www.example.com returns a 200 (OK) response. PR N/A
http://example.com returns a 200 (OK) response. PR N/A
```

I have the rack-rewrite gem in my gem file and the following code in config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
      r301 %r{^/(.*)/$}, '/$1'
    end
```

Doug's blog below helped me get there:
http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/05/19/seo-heroku-ruby-on-rails-and-removing-those-darn-trailing-slashes/

Do you guys know how I can go about getting rid of the duplicate content issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you rent your domain? (GoDaddy, 1&1...)? There might be a solution depending on the specific provider.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve: Only have your App accessible with or without a www in front, or remove the trailing url slashes, or even something else?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm The domain was purchased from godaddy. I just want to make sure that there is not content duplication issues for seo purposes. when I go to the site, there should only be one 200 response... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is actually the simplest. Remove it from your sitemap and/or include it as a restricted page so crawlers don't have access to it. This is what we do when clients have duplicate content on pages they don't want to get rid of.